# IBAction not appearing as an option

Tags: ios, objective-c

in ViewController.h,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *scoreLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed;

@end
```

in ViewController.m,

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Pressed!");
}

@end
```

and I try to connect the button in my ViewController to buttonPressed IBAction by clicking the button while holding Ctrl, and dragging it in the background. I am supposed to see buttonPressed as an option, but I don't see it. How come?

[image]

Comment: For one thing, it looks like you're dragging to/from the wrong thing. You wouldn't see those constraints if you were dragging to/from the view _controller_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here (just go in IB and select your controller in left bar, then go in the last tab of right bar):

[image]

Then you can just drag it to your button and select event for call.